# Cookies disappearing in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httpresponse

I'm working on a REST API Project where users log in and make calls. In order to do that, i create a cookie where i encrypt the username. My server is deployed and something really weird is going on. From time to time i just don't receive the cookies in the response. In this case I just have to make any modification in the web.config file and it starts working again... I really don't understand why... Any ideas ?

Here's my login code :

```
[Route("login", Order = 1)]
[HttpPost]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login([FromUri] string userId, [FromUri] string userPassword)
{
    try
    {
        Tuple<string, string> result = userService.Authenticate(userId, userPassword);

        string sessionIds = result.Item1;
        string message = result.Item2;
        CookieHeaderValue cookie = CreateSessionsCookie(sessionIds);
        cookie.Secure = true;

        // Store username for later use
        CookieHeaderValue userCookie = new CookieHeaderValue(Strings.Id, Encryption.Protect(userId, Strings.Id));
        userCookie.Secure = true;

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message));
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie, userCookie });

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of an anti-pattern to use a cookie for a restful web service. Just include the username in the header instead.

As to why this is timing out I suspect it has to do with your session timing out.